# Unable to verify TCP checksum

Tags: c, linux, networking, checksum, raw-sockets

I have been using raw sockets to create custom TCP packets in C. To verify, I sent them to the loopback interface, and when I checked the received packets using TCPDUMP, the checksum did not match for the TCP packet. Here are the fields in the TCP header :

```
        tcp->th_sport = temp_port;      // The TCP structure. The source port, spoofed, we accept through the command line
        tcp->th_dport = atoi(argv[2]);  // The destination port, we accept through command line
        tcp->th_seq = htonl(random_id()%1000);
        tcp->th_ack = htonl(random_id()%1000);
        tcp->th_off = 5;
        tcp->th_flags = TH_SYN;
        tcp->th_win = 10000;
        tcp->th_sum = 0;
        tcp->th_urp = 0;
        
        //pseudo header for TCP checksum calculation
        p_hdr->source = t1->s_addr;
        p_hdr->dest = t2->s_addr;
        p_hdr->reserved = 0;
        p_hdr->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;  //TCP
        p_hdr->tcp_size = sizeof(struct tcphdr);
        memcpy(buffer2 + sizeof(struct pseudo_tcp_header) , tcp , sizeof(struct tcphdr) );
        tcp->th_sum = htons(csum((unsigned short *) (buffer2 ), sizeof(struct tcphdr) + sizeof(struct pseudo_tcp_header)));
```

This is the random_id function :

```
int random_id()
{
    int lower = 1, upper = 65535,number;
    number = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
    return number;
}
```

And the checksum is computed by the function,

```
unsigned short csum(unsigned short *buf, int len)
{
    unsigned long sum;
    for(sum=0; len>0; len--)
        sum += *buf++;
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum &0xffff);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    return (unsigned short)(~sum);
}
```

Is there a default function to compute the `tcpchecksum` in C ?

Comment: You're not filling in the checksum field with the sum, you're setting it to `0` with `tcp->th_sum = 0;`

Comment: ```tcp->th_sum = htons(csum((unsigned short *) (buffer + sizeof(struct ip)), sizeof(struct tcphdr)));```   , this statement was used to fill in the sum

Comment: Well that's not correct either. You have to compute it over the TCP 'pseudo-header', which includes part of the IP header. There's an RFC on this. Have you read it?

Comment: Ok, Let met check with the TCP pseudo-header, thank you

Comment: It is RFC 1071. Contains C code.

Comment: Tried with the pseudo-header, but not getting the correct result

Comment: Your function does not match the code in the RFC. Notice the RFC uses both an inner and outer loop.

Comment: @RonMaupin Let me check, Thank you, but is there a default function in C for this process?

Comment: "_is there a default function in C for this process?_" No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that there is **no** default function for calculating the `ip`/`tcp` checksum. It can be found by the following code :

```
unsigned short csum(unsigned short *buf, int len)
{
    unsigned long sum;
    for(sum=0; len>0; len--)
        sum += *buf++;
    while (sum>>16)
        sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum &0xffff);
    return (unsigned short)(~sum);
}
```

Where the input, `buf` if the data with the pseudo header.

This calculation is only required if the data packet only traverses through the `localhost`. If it passes the network card to an external network, leave the `sum` field blank. The network card will automatically compute the header value.